# Angle of a line on a certain point

Tags: c#, math, geometry

[image]

I think the image says all. I have to find out the theta for any given line programatically with c#.

```
Point X = new Point(x1,y1);
Point Y = new Point(x2,y2);
```

Now I want to draw a line from X point with theta angle. how can I implement with c#.

**Edit 1:**

[image]

Sorry for poor drawing scale. Here I draw the line and can resize move its position. when I rotate the line 2 PI radians, my x point should have a directional angle like below image. [image]

But you can see, what a mass in the 2nd picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theta (in radians) is:

```
double theta = Math.Atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
```

The end point of a line for the specified `x2` can be calculated as `(x2, theta * (x2 - x1) + y1)`.
Draw line between start point `(x1, x2)` and the end point above on a `Graphics`:

```
g.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, theta * (x2 - x1) + y1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it radian or degree? and what will be the rule to draw a Line on X point with this angle?

Comment: I got an answer. If you could please help me to draw another line, that will be helpful.

Comment: @AbdurRahim Draw in what... GDI? Form canvas? Wpf canvas? OpenGL? DirectX?

Comment: GDI @Jan'splite'Kondelík

Comment: @Dmitry I have done this but my actual problem didn't solve it and I figured out that, angle and line drawing is not the main problem. If you can  help, I am Editing my question little bit.

Comment: I have edited the question with pictures. Please check. @Dmitry

Comment: It's completely unclear. And if you have another question, you should ask it as a separate one.